# Как вывести сумму нечетных чисел циклом от 11 до 30 do-while на PHP

Tags: php, while

Как вывести сумму нечетных чисел  циклом от 11 до 30 do-while на PHP

Comment: 30 - это тридцатое нечётное?

Comment: когда вы закончите учиться, это надо делать так `array_sum(range(11, 30, 2));`

Comment: текста задачи не достаточно, вы должны добавить код ваших попыток, здесь помогают решать, а не решают за вас

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как мы начинаем с нечётного, можно идти с шагом 2:

```
$sum = 0;
$cur = 11;
// if ($cur % 2 === 0) $cur++;
do {
  $sum += $cur;
} while (($cur += 2) < 30);
echo $sum;
```

Однако, скорее всего, от вас ждут проверки в теле цикла:

```
$sum = 0;
$cur = 11;
do {
  if ($cur % 2 === 1) {
    $sum += $cur;
  }
} while (++$cur < 30);
echo $sum;
```

---

Если говорить о чисто арифметическом решении, нужно вспомнить, что сумма n нечётных чисел есть n<sup>2</sup>.
Стало быть сумма нечётных от i до k = k<sup>2</sup> - (i-1)<sup>2</sup>

```
function sum_odd($a, $b) {
    // приходится нормализовать входные данные(получить номера нечётных)
    $a = floor($a/2);
    $b = floor(($b+1)/2);

    return $b*$b - $a*$a;
}

echo sum_odd(11, 29), "\n"; // 200
echo sum_odd(11, 30), "\n"; // 200
echo sum_odd(10, 30), "\n"; // 200
echo sum_odd(10, 29), "\n"; // 200
```

Comment: `$loop` -> `$step` мб таки?

Comment: `$loop` -> `$cur`, пойдёт?

Comment: ой. пардоньте `step` тут вообще не в тему. но `cur` лучше, да  :)

Comment: @vp_arth, ну и решение с array_sum добавьте из комментария к вопросу, чтобы уж все варианты были)

Comment: Разудалите свой ответ, нормальное решение "от Гаусса", а range пусть остаётся в комментарии.